# SimpleXML: how to get node value with a condition on parse rule?

Tags: php, parsing, simplexml, conditional-statements

I have a XML file which was generated by an external entity that I want to parse using SimpleXML. My problem is that in the mapping given by the client I have some conditions in it to get the info I want.

For example, the mapping for the client code is something like this: `E1ADRM1\PARTNER_Q=OSO\E1ADRE1\EXTEND_D` which means that the code for the client is the value of the `EXTEND_D` tag, which is nested in one of the many `PARTNER_Q` tags. The one that has the `OSO` value.

I am starting today to explore SimpleXML, so I have no idea how to get this info.

For what I've read so far, it is pretty simple to get the info of a node, accessing it's properties. If I a single PARTNER_Q and no condition, my `$clientCode` would be `$xml->E1ADRM1->PARTNER_Q->E1ADRE1->EXTEND_D` (right?)

Any hint on how can I get the info having that `PARTNER_Q=OSO` condition in mind?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I'll leave here the code with how I've solved this.
I've Based my code on this [well written answer](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/looping-through-simplexml-nodes/7097/8) that I found.

```
$root = $xml->IDOC;
$shippingPoints = array();
// Go through the list of OTs       
foreach($root->E1EDL20 as $ot) {

    // Instanciate empty OT
    $otInfo = emptyOt();
    $otInfo["refOt"] = trim($ot->VBELN);

    // Go through partner to get the wanted items
    foreach ($ot->E1ADRM1 as $partner) {
            switch ($partner->PARTNER_Q) {
                    case "OSO":
                            $otInfo["codeLoader1"] = trim($partner->E1ADRE1->EXTEND_D);

                            break;
                    case "OSP":
                            $otInfo["refShip"] = trim($partner->PARTNER_ID);
                            // get the shipping info if not already fetched
                            if(!isset($shippingPoints[$otInfo["refShip"]])) {
                                    $shippingPoints[$otInfo["refShip"]] = Whouses::getWhouseAddressByCode($otInfo["refShip"]);
                            }
                            // assign values
                            $otInfo["brandNameShip"] = $shippingPoints[$otInfo["refShip"]]["name"];
                            $otInfo["addrShip1"] = $shippingPoints[$otInfo["refShip"]]["address"];
                            $otInfo["cityShip"] = $shippingPoints[$otInfo["refShip"]]["city"];
                            $otInfo["zipShip"] = $shippingPoints[$otInfo["refShip"]]["zipcode"];
                            $otInfo["countryShip"] = $shippingPoints[$otInfo["refShip"]]["country"];

                            break;
                    case "WE":
                            $otInfo["refDeliv"] = trim($partner->PARTNER_ID);
                            $otInfo["addrDeliv1"] = trim($partner->STREET1);
                            $otInfo["cityDeliv"] = trim($partner->CITY1);
                            $otInfo["zipDeliv"] = trim($partner->POSTL_COD1);
                            $otInfo["countryDeliv"] = trim($partner->COUNTRY1);
                    default:
                            // do nothing
                            break;
            }
    }

    // Go through the dates info to get the wanted items
    foreach ($ot->E1EDT13 as $qualf) {
            switch ($qualf->QUALF) {
                    case "006":
                            $dtDeliv = trim($qualf->NTANF);
                            $timeDeliv = trim($qualf->NTANZ);
                            $otInfo["initialDtDeliv"] = convertToOtDateFormat($dtDeliv, $timeDeliv);

                            break;
                    case "007":
                            $initialDtShip = trim($qualf->NTANF);
                            $timeInitialDtShip = trim($qualf->NTANZ);
                            $otInfo["initialDtShip"] = convertToOtDateFormat($initialDtShip, $timeInitialDtShip);

                            break;
                    default:
                            // do nothing
                            break;
            }
    }
}
```

Hope this'll help someone!